# Ubuntu 13.10 with encryption installed manually won't load on SSD

Tags: 13.10, encryption, disk-usage, unallocated

I want to install Ubuntu 13.10 on my new SSD drive in laptop. I have no other OS and want to use whole disk for Ubuntu installation. However, I've read that it's best to leave some unallocated space on SSD to extend its lifetime. I also want to use a whole disk encryption to secure all my data. And that's the problem: a default installing option that allows you to use encryption doesn't allow to manage partitioning details before installation.

Of course I tried to perform manual partitioning using 'something else' option in Ubuntu installer. I've followed instructions at [this](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/10/how-to-setup-encrypted-ubuntu-installation/) website to createa  separate boot partition and  encrypted partition for the OS and I have left some unallocated space. I have left default options of installing the loader on /dev/sda instead of a particular partition. However, after completing installation successfully I cannot access my OS, for there is no GRUB loading at startup, and BIOS does not detect any hard drive in 'boot device' option. I tried to manually install grub from liveCD, but the permission to disk was denied.

Earlier, when I was using a default setting 'erase disk and install Ubuntu', everything was working fine, but there was no unallocated space on SSD and shrinking an encrypted partition using command line is far too difficult for me.

I'm not that familiar with linux systems, so maybe I'm doing some stupid mistake that can be easily solved?